# native typeface cannot be made При замене шрифта

Tags: java, android, шрифты, typeface

Всем привет:
Кто баловался со шрифтами и ставил свои в приложение:
Делаю так:
папка: `assets/fonts/mistra.ttf`
в классе к которому привязан xml 
пишу

```
TextView tv;
Typeface face;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.a1);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eda);
face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mistral.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
}
```

и вижу такую ошибку:
native typeface cannot be made
ссылается на строку

```
face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mistral.ttf");
```

Comment: Проблема конкретно с этим шрифтом, или любым?

Comment: И assets располагаются под каталогом main или resources?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Martynenko
другие не пробовал
папка app\src\main\assets

Comment: Попробуйте вариант `src/main/assets/mistral.ttf `, и использовать его `"mistral.ttf"`. Также попробуйте другие шрифты.

Comment: А шрифт mistrial.ttf у вас там точно лежит? У вас в вопросе указан font.ttf. Попробуйте другой какой-нибудь шрифт добавить.

Comment: так mistra.ttf или mistral.ttf?

Comment: @ Андроид Андроид 
@ Vyacheslav Martynenko
https://yadi.sk/i/iT3w0x3LrBpBc

Comment: ВСЕМ СПАСИБО!РАзобрался!ошибка в имени файла шрифта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас скорее всего идет утечка памяти. Правильно грузить будет вот так `Utils.getTypeFace(ctx, "fonts/mistral.ttf")`

```
public class Utils {

private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, String assetPath) {
            synchronized (cache) {
                if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                    try {
                        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), assetPath);
                        cache.put(assetPath, typeFace);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("TypeFaces", "Typeface not loaded.");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return cache.get(assetPath);
            }
        }
}
```

В этом случае вы защитите свое приложение от утечки, так как шрифт будет загружены 1 раз и на всю сессию приложения.

**UPD**

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eda);
face = Utils.getTypeFace(this, "fonts/mistral.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: а можно инструкцию к вашему примеру)

Comment: Создайте класс Utils или любой другой. поместите в него код описанный выше. Замените вашу строчку face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mistral.ttf"); на face = Utils.getTypeFace(this, "fonts/mistral.ttf");

Comment: @upword обновил

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, а если у меня несколько активностей,мне в каждой писать 
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eda);
face = Utils.getTypeFace(this, "fonts/mistral.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);

Comment: @upward В таком случае Создайте кастомный TextView. и в xml ссылайтесь на него

Comment: @upward http://stackoverflow.com/a/7197867/2667883 по этой ссылке есть пример,